# Remove items from ObservableConcurrentCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` with `ItemsSource` bound in XAML to an [ObservableConcurrentCollection](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples) property.

This allows me to update the collection from a worker thread, and have the changes automatically reflected in my `DataGrid`.

The problem is that I can only add items to that collection. I need to be able to remove items but I can't find any method that does that.

Does `ObservableConcurrentCollection` allow removing items? If not, is there an alternative collection I can use?

Comment: Does the `ObservableCollection` not fit your needs? Or you want specific Asyn Observable collection then use `AsyncObservableCollectoin` (Read about it here - https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/10023516)

Comment: Like I mentioned, it works great for adding items, but I need to be able to remove them, which doesn't seem to be possible. I'll check your link. Thanks

Comment: If that implementation of an observable collection does not allow to remove items, you should certainly search for an alternative.

Comment: @user1672994 ObservableCollection does not handle modifications from another thread, that's why I was using ObservableConcurrentCollection. I tried with AsyncObservableCollection and it's working fine for now! You can put it in an answer if you like ;) thanks !

Comment: Thanks @iMezouar - Will put it as Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `AsyncObservableCollection` which provides feature to update the collection from worker Thread and allows Remove operation. You can read copy the code from `https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/10023516`.

Comment: This collection is not thread safe though, right?

Comment: Dont know why this is called "Async", nothing async about it. But it is threadsafe. 
It simply synchronizes all calls to the thread that created the collection.
Very nice for apps with a UI thread. Thanks!